# Paths and exporting

Tags: opengl, codeblocks

I am using textures whilst within code blocks- and this is the path that I am using:

C:\Users\Samuel\Documents\Documents\projects\test\MapCreator\sand.png

My question is - once I export my project, won't this path change? And if so how do I remedy this?

I am using C++, codeblocks, and freeglut, along with SOIL

Additionally is it better to have one large texture, and only use a certain part of it or is it better to have multiple textures?

Answer (score 0):

Try [working-directory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Working_directory)-relative or [`GetModuleFileName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683197%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)-relative paths/filenames.